# Getting error 87 at payment Authorize.net in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorize.net

I have created a test account with Authorize.net. My development environment is rails 3 and I am trying to implement the Server Integration Method (SIM) by using static IP. But I am getting an error:

> "3,1,87,(TESTMODE) Transactions of this market type cannot be processed on this system.,000000,P,0,,,199.00,,auth_capture,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,D3EA25CA1DF97765286A48C6B22287F4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,✓,uSIUUgX0d++dIheYjcHdlztlViD/r4YDUP9rEuEy9U8=,Purchase" when send request to "AuthorizeNet::SIM::Transaction::Gateway::TEST" gateway.

I also found this link: [others got similar type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132450/failtestmode-transactions-of-this-market-type-cannot-be-processed-on-this-sys)

But not helpful. Any suggestions how to resolve this error? I wrote following codes in the action.

```
@amount = 10.00
@sim_transaction = AuthorizeNet::SIM::Transaction.new('API Login ID', 'Transaction Key', @amount, :hosted_payment_form => true)  
@sim_transaction.set_hosted_payment_receipt(AuthorizeNet::SIM::HostedReceiptPage.new(:link_method => AuthorizeNet::SIM::HostedReceiptPage::LinkMethod::GET, :link_text => 'Continue', :link_url => payments_thank_you_url(:only_path => false)))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fail:(TESTMODE) Transactions of this market type cannot be processed on this system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132450/failtestmode-transactions-of-this-market-type-cannot-be-processed-on-this-sys)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with credit card transactions through web applications, you need to make sure your Sandbox account is of "Card Not Present" type. If you don't remember which type you set it to, it is a good idea to create a new account and make sure to select "Card Not Present" option. Otherwise, you will get this error message.

I hope this helps.